# QGIS: Cannot add negative numbers in a field

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, null

I am using QGIS 3.4 and when I finish drawing a feature (line), I try to add a negative value (-1) in the attribute dialog and it is automatically changed to NULL. The field is integer.

Even if I leave it NULL and then open the attribute table and try to edit it there, it still does not let me use a negative number - automatically changes to NULL. The only way is to change it using Field Calculator and update the existing field to -1.

I tried the same in version 2.18.17 and it works fine.

I haven't used QGIS for years and I am not entirely familiar with the changes in the latest versions. Is there a new setting/option that I don't know of?

**EDIT :**

I have reported the bug and it has now been fixed.

[PostGIS/geojson: Cannot input negative numbers in int fields](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32149)

The new QGIS versions won't have this issue

Comment: What format is the feature you are trying to create? e.g. shapefile or PostGIS. I cannot seem to replicate this.

Comment: PostGIS. I will check if it's the same with shp

Comment: The same happens with shp

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Integer64 field type to store negative integers.

Although I can't find any specific reference to this.

Comment: You're right, int64 allows me to add negative numbers manually. I don't understand though why I cannot do the same with int.

Comment: it's bug (thanks @fing-lixon).

I have tested with QGIS 3.10, it's works, also with int

Answer (score 2):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32149).  Both in the attribute dialog and the attribute table itself, attempting to enter a negative integer yields a NULL value when focus is moved off the value.  Using the [field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) allows the entry of negative integers.

Comment: I have reported the bug in github and they have fixed it (please see my edit in the original post). Hopefully in the new releases this will be fixed.

Comment: As for your workaround, yes this is a solution (exactly how I am working right now) but is a damn waste of time to create features leaving the negative fields blank and then going back to the attribute table to use the calculator to fill them!

Comment: @Gunganis thank you. I've edited my answer to reference your issue report.

Comment: @Gunganis also thank you for reporting the bug.